# I want to write a if condition based in what url my user was before being took for the specific cart view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm building an ecommerce site and I built a specific view to handle with adding products in a cart, and after the product is added, my user is redirect to a store. But here is the thing, I want to see if my user was in the store view, where are all the products, of if he was in the product_detail view, where it shows only a specific user. So, if the user was in the store view, I want him to be redirected, after the product was added in the cart, to the store view. But if he was in the product_detail view, I want him to be redirected to this product_detail view.
So basically I want to find a way to see in what view, or url, my user was, and then redirect in this way. I also would like to only use Django and no JavaScript, if it's possible.

Here is my view that add a product to cart.

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug) 
order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(  
    product=product,
    user=request.user
)
order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, complete=False) 
if order_qs.exists():   
    order = order_qs[0] 
    if order.products.filter(product__slug=product.slug).exists(): 
        order_item.quantity += 1  
        order_item.save()     
        messages.info(request, 'This item quantity was updated')
    else:
        order.products.add(order_item)  
        messages.info(request, 'This item was added to your cart') 
else:
    order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user)  
    order.products.add(order_item)  
    messages.info(request, 'This item was added to your cart')

return redirect('store')
```

Comment: just use `request.META.HTTP_REFERER` to access previous url

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return redirect('store')
```

Try adding:

```
return redirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", "store"))
```

This will redirect to the referring page, and your named URL `store` will be a fallback redirect.

It's worth noting that you may at some point require multiple redirects based on conditions, in which case there's no reason you can't add them like so:

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug) 
order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(  
    product=product,
    user=request.user
)
order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, complete=False) 
if order_qs.exists():   
    order = order_qs[0] 
    if order.products.filter(product__slug=product.slug).exists(): 
        order_item.quantity += 1  
        order_item.save()     
        messages.info(request, 'This item quantity was updated')
        return redirect(request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", "store"))
    else:
        order.products.add(order_item)  
        messages.info(request, 'This item was added to your cart') 
        return redirect('some_other_page')
else:
    order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user)  
    order.products.add(order_item)  
    messages.info(request, 'This item was added to your cart')
    return redirect('store')
```